# Keycloak: Do not create local user while identity brokering

Tags: java, keycloak

I am using keycloak as an identity broker to SAML identity provider in order to login to web application.

To get it work I have created new authentication flow which looks like: "Create User If Unique", "Automatically Link Brokered Account".

Keycloak redirects correctly to the identity provider with the login page. After login identity provider redirects as expected to keycloak and then to my web application but keycloak also creates local user.

Is it possible to use external IDP without local users creation?

The problem with local users : I have "custom user federation" implementation which fetch users from my application and if local user created it's not possible login to keycloak using "custom user federation". Keycloak will just try login like with local user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to skip the creation of local user account. According to the Keycloak team, they are deferring the support "as we are planning on some larger work to the storage layer which will make it possible to deliver on this capabiltiy".
See Feature Request https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4429.

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)